# How effective would a scythe be in a one-on-one, sword-versus-scythe fight?

Tags: weapons, medieval, combat, death, tactics

In one-on-one combat, with one combatant using a sword, the other the aforementioned false Death, how effective would a scythe be in combat? What tactics could be utilized with it, and what tactics could be utilized against it?

This does not involve modifying the scythe in any way, and is purely out of the two combatants’ skill with their respective weapons. You can assume that both are well-versed in the usage of their weapon.

Comment: There is a youtube video on this. Shadversity I think. Or maybe Skallagrim or Lindyberge. The answer was not very. Scythes are designed to cut towards you, not away from you.

Comment: It’s probably just me, but I’m not quite clear on the difference between cutting toward or away. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Looking around my larger hand tools, I would chose any of them as a weapon over the scythe. It's heavy and awkward....even a flimsy fan rack would have more chance of being effective!

Comment: Just to say before voting to close as a duplicate - there might be an advantage for a scythe wealder who swings horizontally at their opponent's ankles or feet, swordsmen aren't trained to expect that.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I got some answers before this page ceases to be. At this point, I’ll close it when possible. I’m not familiar enough with the platform to do so myself.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks.

Comment: Accept the answer u like and it counts as u got what u were looking for. Questions aren't closed here and if they are fit the wb topic/rules they are open forever for new answers, for updates or whatever. Happens not so often but theoretically.

Comment: A person with a scythe would probably get killed on the battlefield, but it would depend on their skills. I mean, look at Kronos from Greek Mythology. He defeated all of his 11 brothers and sister titans, and almost defeated the gods while wielding a scythe. But, sadly, that's Greek Mythology, not real life. So I would say that it would depend on that person's abilities and skills basically anywhere where people want to kill them.

Comment: @DKNguyen: The conventional scythe is designed to cut approximately perpendicular to you, and to cut very near ground level.  Any other motion is (in my experience, at least) quite awkward.  So you might cut your opponent's feet off at the ankles (unless he's wearing really good boots), but meanwhile he has stabbed you through the heart, or cut your throat.

Comment: Unlike the proposed duplicate this question focuses specifically on a one on one fight where one side wields a sword and the other wields a scythe. This question is much more specific. It also does not allow any modifications to the scythe, unlike the proposed duplicate. @Bill I think you should edit the title of your query to reflect that you are interested in sword vs scythe fights only.

Comment: @jamesqf Not sure what your definition of "perpendicular to you" is. Even if you mean perpendicular to the direction you are facing, it seems to me that would be an axe not a scythe, because when you swing a handle, that handle swings perpendicular to the length of the lever and an axe has the blade facing the direction of the swing whereas a scythe blade mostly faces inward towards the wielder.

Comment: I don't remember the rules on linking external content, but there's a video on YouTube that might be worth watching. "Underappreciated Historical Weapons: the War Scythe" by Shadiversity goes into details about why the farming scythe is a terrible weapon, but that there was a variant of it that is a decent weapon.

Comment: Consider the [war scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe); the fact that these were actually used in combat indicates that they aren't that bad as weapons, though they don't much resemble the scythe used for farming.

Comment: While this really doesn't address the intent of the question, I'd like to note that a [*sickle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sickle) is used for almost exactly the same purpose as a scythe, but would make a *far* more effective weapon.

Comment: @DKNguyen:  I mean that when you use a scythe, the blade mostly moves from your left to your right, not towards you.  (So it really helps to be right handed.  I don't know if left handed scythes ever existed.) The blade is pointed mostly away from you.

Comment: @Bill by "cut towards you" it means a scythe blade's cutting edge is pointed towards you the wielder all the time, it can only cut by reaching around a target and pulling the scythe back towards you. so to even work you need to execute an extra step over nearly any other weapon.

Comment: for those unfamiliar with scythes this may help this may be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xImLQ24-iXE

Comment: The scythe is effective simply because it is a common agricultural tool.. The choice is **not** between scythe or sword, it is between scythe or a stick you picked up from the ground.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They guy with the scythe is toast.

Yes, it does terrible damage when it connects, but the required swing is too long and the weapon too heavy to recover quickly; someone with a properly balanced sword (lighter than a full greatsword), who isn't disabled by sheer bad luck on the first scythe swing will cut the scythe wielder to pieces before they can recover for another swing.

Scythes work very well for their intended purpose: harvesting grain (a sharp scythe wielded by a practiced user can compete closely with a gasoline powered sickle bar mower with similar swath width), but it does this by doing a lot of work on each stroke, not by getting a lot of strokes in.  Combat weapons, by contrast, need to generate a lot of strokes because if they don't, the opponent who does will always win.

Comment: Good to know. Just to be certain, you do mean the stereotypical “Grim Reaper” kind of scythe?

Comment: That's the only tool correctly called a scythe.

Comment: Okay then. Good to know.

Comment: There's a very good Lindybeige video on Youtube on this topic - basically scythes are good for cutting grass and people who are willing to act like a piece of grass and rubbish for everything else.  Actually, he's done two videos!

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 That may be where I saw the comparison in work rate between a scythe and a sickle bar mower.

Comment: @Bill https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bardiche this one is how proper conversion of scythe may look like 90 rotation and bent and sharpened from different side.(and sure it has more metal, so no real conversion is possible, in a simple way)

Comment: The scythe as a weapon comes down from peasants fighting with whatever was handy -- same source as the (very effective) *naginata*, most flails, several weapons that look like rakes -- and all of them are more useful as weapons than a scythe.  You use a scythe as a weapon if it's the only one you have.

Comment: It depends what you are fighting. Two peasants with scythes would win against a horseman every time - though only one peasant might get taken out on the first attack.

Comment: "...the weapon [is] ***too heavy to recover quickly***" (emphasis added) — as someone who owns a scythe, I cannot emphasize enough how accurate this point is. They're also stupidly ineffective as weapons, at least in the configuration intended for cutting grass/crops. On the plus side, if wanna-be Death is at all practiced with the thing, (s)he will have impressive strength and stamina.

Comment: "Two peasants with scythes would win against a horseman every time" -- sure, using the scythes as hooks to unhorse the rider, whichever one the rider doesn't cut down immediately will get him off the horse, and then have time to wind up for a stroke while the guy tries to recover from hitting the ground.  Same thing is true with pitchforks, garden rakes, or pretty much anything else that combines hook and spear/blade.  This is what most pole arms with heads more complex than a plain spear were designed to do.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question is, sadly, not so very straight forward. There are so many variables to consider that the answer will always be up for debate. It is never a "yes/no" question, but one of probability and stacking advantages. Someone can always "get lucky" when it comes to fighting, especially when you introduce weapons into the mix.

As such I will give you a tl;dr of my answer. If it's a purpose built War Scythe, then the longer weapon has an advantage, if it's a common farming scythe then you'd be better off using a long stick. Now on to the details.

---

The first question you have to ask is, "what kind of scythe are they using specifically?"

If the answer is "[War Scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe)," then the answer I have to give is this:

The advantage will typically go to the person with the longest purpose-built weapon. The War Scythe even has a [treaties featuring them](https://www.sbc.org.pl/dlibra/publication/235272/edition/222462/content?format_id=2).
[image: Image of a War Scythe]

---

If you are using an unmodified Farming Scythe then I will say this:

The one using the sword will likely have the advantage because of the design and characteristics of a scythe which I will go over now.
The most glaring flaw with this farming instrument is the protruding handle on the shaft. It is meant to be held and used in the fashion as demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGNTYPmeLXk) and in the picture below.
[image: Proper Scythe Grip]

This means that the majority of [pole-arm techniques](http://www.thearma.org/Manuals/Vadi.htm) employed could not be used as they require free range of your hands to travel up and down the shaft of the weapon unimpeded. [Here is an example using a spear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdPQbCzZXnY). Notice the constant sliding of the hands around the shaft of the weapon, a common theme with all pole weapons/long-shafted weapons (though perhaps not to the degree of a spear, obviously).

Also note how the scythe is down low to the ground by default, assuming you are holding it proper grip. This leaves you almost totally exposed on one side, a fatal flaw if there ever was one. You also restrict yourself to the 2, 4, and 6 strikes as seen below.

[image: Cutting Directions Chart]

This means one entire side of your body is exposed to attack with no reasonable means to defend that side.

Some things that it does have going for it is that it would be easy to preform sweeps with it, that is hooking the back of someone's legs and tripping them. Also attacks to the legs, in general, would very swift and difficult to avoid.

---

I could go on, of course, but this article is getting lengthy enough. So my conclusion is this, the purpose-built tool typically wins. In this case the order of likely hood to succeed is as follows War Scythe>Sword>Unmodified Farming Scythe.

Comment: I don't disagree *per se* (and there's a lot of other good info here), but I'll note that longer reach weapons aren't *necessarily* better in a one-on-one duel. In such instances, the more *maneuverable* weapon may be preferred. Now, if we're talking about opposing *formations*...

Comment: @Mattthew This is true, as you say, _necessarily_, but _generally_, the range advantage is just that, an advantage. You still have to get around that extra length to get into your range, putting you in danger. This is where maneuverability would come into play, as a weapon that is easier to manipulate could make a faster counter attack. This is a big disadvantage to heavier weapons. This is a prime example of how there is rarely a "right" answer, but a "better within context" answer.

Answer (score 3):

I actually have a scythe, and used it for scything grass.  It is definitely not suitable as a weapon.

The scythe has a curved blade.  It is designed to slice grass off considering that it has mild resistance.  Depending on the blade, it can cut through very THIN branches.  It will NOT cut through bone.  The blade is designed to push grass to the side as you conplete the sweep.  It cannot cut straight through a thick object, because the back of the blade is angled and thick.

The blade is angled to have clearance above the ground.  It is designed to cut at a very precise angle.  If you try to swing it at something not utilizing the held-above-the-ground technique, you will not get the proper cutting angle.  The cutting edge is also quite thin, and just cutting grass with it requires rehoning the blade in-field every couple minutes.  If you attempt to combat with it, it will get dull before you can even beat one person.

So, not only will you be unable to cut through, your blade will get stuck on the first strike, and if you manage to pull it out after that, it'll also no longer be operable.

Answer (score 0):

I gave your girl a scythe, bgirljungli.  I hope you and she do not mind.

https://www.deviantart.com/bgirljungli/art/girl-holding-staff-29003855

[image: girl with scythe]

The trick to fighting with a scythe is that you are fighting.  It is a staff - use it like one.  Scythe vs sword is dumb if all you are going to do is swing the scythe like you are mowing.  Quarterstaff vs sword is a whole different deal.  A quarterstaff is blunt but it has more reach than a sword, much more leverage, and it more effectively uses both hands of the fighter.  And the quarterstaff is quicker:  both ends of the quarterstaff are weapons and the attack with one end readies the attack by the other.

It cannot cut, unless your quarterstaff is a scythe.  With the staff held close to the blade it can be used as a slashing sword and the point is sharp.  The leverage of the staff makes cutting moves possible that would be less effective with a sword.  And as pointed out the great reach of the scythe opens the possibility of devastating sweep attacks on an opponent who is backing away.

---

A scythe optimally used as a weapon would not be used in the same way as scythe as an agricultural tool.  It could be an awesome weapon.

Comment: I imagine you have never actually handled a scythe. If you tried to fight as shown in the picture, you are correct it would be a very effective weapon - for injuring yourself.  If you want to use a scythe as a quarter staff, leave the blade at home and just use the handle!

Comment: @alephzero - we scythe fighters put in long hours of practice.

Comment: Trying to use a scythe as a staff is impractical; note Fuzzy Ferret's answer. Even if you take off the blade and handle, you're left with something excessively heavy and oddly shaped, compared to a *proper* quarterstaff. I have to concur with alephzero in wondering if you've ever actually handled a scythe. (Admittedly, not many people *have* these days...)

Comment: I cant believe you toads are calling me out personally about the scythe!  I considered one but thought it would be too scary for the neighbors and so I use a [swing blade](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/lawn-and-garden/gardening-tools/gardening-hand-tools/7720246) .  With the sling blade you can cut on the backstroke too which is good.   And there was a rusty one they let me buy for $18!

Comment: Huh, that's a new name to me; I know them as "grass whips". I have one of those, also, and let me assure you, there is a *world* of difference. A grass whip would actually make a decently scary weapon (those suckers are sharper than they look!), although I suspect you'd have trouble doing more than superficial damage. They're also *designed* to be swung and are much, *much* lighter than a scythe. (And they're pretty terrible for actually mowing grass, at least the sort of grass you *want* in a lawn. Good for thicker weeds, though.)

Comment: @Matthew - I am glad I went with the grass whip then.  I was sure I would break the scythe on rocks,  I take divots like crazy with the grass whip and it strikes sparks off the rocks but it is a beast..

Comment: @Willk as someone who has used both I can tell you a whip cutter uses a completely different motion, is MUCH lighter (2lbs vs 6), and has two cutting edge on a very different orientation. they are similar in purpose not usage or function.